# Incorrect syntax near drop table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to write the following SQL query, however there are incorrect syntax errors with drop table `@temp` and
create table `@temp`, why is it that? (Using SQL Server 2015)

```
DECLARE @temp NVARCHAR(10)
SET @temp='sth'
IF OBJECT_ID(@temp, 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE  @temp
CREATE TABLE @temp
```

Comment: you need dynamic sql

Comment: missing "go" delimiter if you run this in sql server studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question WHY, it is a syntactic convention from days long past.
The DROP statement goes like this:

```
    DROP TABLE MyTable
```

and *not* like this:

```
    DROP TABLE 'MyTable'
```

`MyTable` is an identifier, and identifiers in SQL are not quoted. And because it uses no quotes, it does not accept variables.

Also compare with a `WHERE` clause:

```
    WHERE MyCol = 'abc'
    -- MyCol is not quoted because it is an identifier.
    -- 'abc' is quoted because it is a value, and so it can be replaced by a variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TEMP) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #TEMP;
```