# Using a String to retrieve a column from a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL and trying to assign value to a variable from the value returned by a function but I am unable to get the value.

My query is :

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,@ReferenceDateString VARCHAR(10)='Q1_CY' ;

Select @StartDate=@ReferenceDateString from dbo.Dates(GETDATE());
```

When I run the above query I just get the value `Q1_CY` assgined to `@StartDate` rather than the actual value from the function.

If I don't want to use a variable then my query looks like:

```
Select @StartDate=Q1_CY from dbo.Dates(GETDATE());
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: You may try `SET @StartDate = SELECT....`.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL to do this.  If you are learning SQL, skip this and go on to something else, until you are more comfortable with the language.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you please post the Dynamic SQL so that I can understand and try it as I am totally not new to SQL but new to Dynamic SQL.

Comment: What `dbo.Dates()` function returns?

Comment: The function returns date. In this case, it is going to return the value of 'Q1_CY'.

Comment: Please see my previous answer to a rather similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40102630/1220550

Comment: Please post the signature of dbo.Dates

Answer (score 0):

It is rather cumbersome in dynamic SQL because you need an output parameter:

```
declare @StartDate DATETIME,
        @ReferenceDateString VARCHAR(10)='Q1_CY' ;
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'Select @StartDate = @ReferenceDateString from dbo.Dates(GETDATE())';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@ReferenceDateString', @ReferenceDateString);

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@StartDate datetime output', @StartDate=@StartDate;
```